# Nativescript app crashes after inactivity or multitasking

Tags: android, oncreate, nativescript

My NS app for Android crashes after I suspend it and do some multitasking or after longer inactivity. Maybe because of the inappropriate garbage colletion. Do you have any idea to fix this? My NS version is 1.6. Error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.yyy.yy/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException:
```

Calling js method onCreate failed

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_onAttached' of null
File: "/data/data/com.yyy.yy/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame.js, line: 414, column: 16
```

StackTrace:

```
Frame: function:'NativeActivity.onCreate',      file:'/data/data/com.yyy.yy/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 414, column: 17

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2661)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an open GitHub issue for this on the [Nativescript repo](https://github.com/nativescript/nativescript).

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting [the proper link to the issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/1614).

After testing the package the latest user sent, the team did not reproduce the problem. Version 1.7 is about to be released with the fix included.